# Why aren't the humans wearing environmental suits in Star Wars spacecraft?

Tags: star-wars, astronauts

When NASA sends astronauts to space, they have to wear uncomfortable suits. Why aren't the humans in Star Wars spacecraft doing the same thing? What technology do they have on board that remove this need?

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the question to get 2 negative votes? Please explain so that I can improve my question in future.

Comment: I wasn't one of the down-voters, but my guess is that they felt the answer to this question is too obvious. Because this is a science fiction site, many of the users here have seen/read a lot of sci-fi, and they're used to knowing the conventions of sci-fi space travel without having to think about it. The new Star Wars film is so popular that at least some of the audience will be quite new to sci-fi, so I think the question is okay. :)

Comment: @ Renegade Princess, thanks. I thought it was a logical question to ask.

Comment: Who says they're humans?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Real-world astronauts wear bulky space suits to protect themselves from extreme cold, radiation, and a lack of breathable atmosphere.

They only wear the suits if they are planning to enter such an environment (such as going outside their space station, or walking on the moon) or if they're about to do something dangerous where they are facing a higher risk of being exposed to such an environment (such as taking off or landing their spacecraft).

On board the International Space Station they do not wear the bulky space suits while going about their day-to-day activities.

Star Wars is similar. Most people on space ships do not wear protective suits, because the ship itself provides the air, warmth and protection they need.

Unlike our current real-world spacecraft, ships in Star Wars usually provide artificial gravity as well.

Comment: ...except for that time Han, Leia, and Chewie walked outside the Millennium Falcon while landed inside a big cavern on an asteroid.  They did have breathers, but it doesn't seem possible there's enough pressure to keep your blood from boiling.

Comment: The giant slug generated his own internal atmosphere. Yeah, that's it!

Comment: @ScottWhitlock the hand-wavy explanation for this is that the creature they're inside is providing both warmth and pressure as part of its internal environment. There are also mynocks (those flying lamprey things) alive and well in there. Not exactly "realistic", but Star Wars doesn't aim for that. Star Wars is definitely an atmosphere over explanation kind of work. (Pun intended. :D)

Comment: Except the giant slug had its mouth open (apparently) the whole time, or at least while flying in and out.  Seems pretty open-to-space to me.  It's a galaxy far, far away, so maybe their galaxy has an atmosphere.  :)

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Your blood doesn't actually boil in space. Your skin provides enough pressure to prevent that. They'd still have been damn cold standing in what's essentially open vacuum though.

Comment: @sevvack Interestingly enough, the cold bit isn't true either. Sure space is "cold" in the sense that in most places in space there's no heat source nearby - but that doesn't mean all heat is magically sucked out of your body. The only way you're losing heat in space is by radiation and through the surfaces you touch. That's a very slow process.

Comment: "The pressure in the vacuum of space is so low that the boiling point of the fluids in your body decreases below the body’s normal temperature (37oC), which results in the formation of gas bubbles in your fluids that can really mess you up. You’ll swell up pretty bad, perhaps even up to twice your normal size, but you won’t explode as your skin is very stretchy. Your blood will also not boil. You will, of course, be in an immense amount of pain and your blood circulation will be impeded." [Source](http://www.iflscience.com/space/what-would-happen-your-body-space-without-spacesuit/)

Comment: @sevvack: “Your blood doesn't actually boil in space.” Maybe *your* blood doesn’t!

Answer (score 3):

In the case of the X-Wing pilots, for a spacesuit to do any good it would have to survive the explosive destruction of your ship intact and then be able to keep you alive until you were rescued. The odds of this are probably pretty low. On the other hand a bulky pressure suit would probably reduce your piloting ability, making it more likely that you would be destroyed. So probably a net loss.

At one point in the Battle of Yavin one of the pilots shouts to another "Eject! Eject!", suggesting that X-Wings have some kind of ejector seat capability that can keep the pilot alive in space. Maybe the entire sealed cockpit is ejected, or perhaps a force field maintains enough atmospheric pressure, or perhaps some clever mechanism envelopes the pilot in a sealed bubble as part of the ejection sequence; we never find out.

Answer (score -2):

If you look closely, you can actually see several characters in the Mos Eiesly cantina wearing space suits, not to mention BoShek, and Bossk from Empire Strikes back.

Comment: Mos Eisely is a cantina on a planet.  It is not in space.  What has it got to do with why characters *don't* need to wear space suits in space?

Comment: @PaulL If people sometimes wear spacesuits in spaceports, then they presumably wear them in space sometimes. I suppose that's what this answer is saying.

Comment: @anaranjada: Maybe. An alternate explanation is that the atmospheric conditions on Tatooine are poisonous or otherwise dangerous to the beings in the "spacesuits", so they need those suits to survive in the local environment.

Comment: @GreenMatt Maybe so, good point. "Mos Eisley Spaceport: You'll never find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy. And they allow smoking indoors: better wear your spacesuit."

Comment: @anaranjada maybe, except the question wasn't "Does anyone wear Spacesuits in Star Wars?", it was "Why *aren't* they wearing space suits?".  Pointing out that a couple people might doesn't at all address the question as to how those who aren't are able not to.

Comment: Are they space suits, or some sort of armor or other suit that just happens to look, or maybe even act like a space suit? The armor the clones wore doubled as environmental/space suits as well. But that wasn't their primary purpose.